# wsdl with iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wsdl

I am trying to integrate WSDL with iPhone.

I compiled the project wsdl2objc I compiled it, and execute it browse the wsdl but it did not translated it to objective C or something.. any other libraries you recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check out sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com/).

It does the same as what you actually need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try using http://sudzc.com/ I think its better than wsdl2objc